# Describing the non-summative combination of proportions

Tags: probability, proportion

I'm sure this an obvious question for someone.

When one combines proportions, but the overall proportion cannot exceed 100 % in reality - what is this called? For example, if I'm trying to reduce the likelihood of someone catching a disease and a medication reduces the probability by 80% and following a meal plan reduces it by 40% (independent studies no interaction measured) then the overall reduction is worked out as follows:
80% + (40% of 20%) = 88%. I may have reduced the likelihood of someone catching the disease by 88%.

How do I explain this mathematically? I know there's a probabilistic basis to this (is it the independent events side of things in basic probability, is it something to do with asymptotes, is it something to do with the math behind ANOVAs (i.e. interactions and independent)?). Is it all of these things combined?!

I'm happy to head off on my own for further research I just need to know I heading to the right literature as i'm not a natural statistician!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The closest I can match is "intersection" and "rule of multiplication of probability." Most people who didn't nap through their mathematics classes should not be surprised by what you showed in the question.

Comment: I perceived the end of your response to be slightly insulting. If intended, it was unnecessary and contributes to the reluctance of people to engage with things they aren't naturally good at. Aside from that, the 1st part of your response was helpful and has pushed me toward making further connections with other topics. Often, even with degree-level stats courses, one can achieve high grades without really understanding basics and how it all ties together. We need to recognise that not everyone knows the same information to the same extent and we all have value. At least I'm trying.

Comment: Jerome, Although I cannot read @penguin_knight's mind, I suspect he was referring to your intended audience and not to you.  After all, you did not ask for an answer; you asked *how to "explain this".*  He may be suggesting that you might already have succeeded with a mathematical explanation in your question statement and that it's sufficiently simple to be persuasive to most people.

Comment: Hello whuber, yes perhaps more of a projection of my own insecurities showing through there in my interpretation. I genuinely apologise Penguin_Knight if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks @whuber. And Jerome, I meant exactly what I said, most of your audience should have gone through some classes about this rule, they will not feel what you described a very outlandish idea. No apology needed and don't worry about insecurity; I hang out here all the time and I am not even a statistician nor mathematician. If you hang around longer you'll find that we are actually pretty cool.

Comment: I'm still actually confused. Perhaps I've used some misleading words in my question 'independent studies no interaction measured'. In fact, what I meant was these probabilities are from separate published studies, on different samples. I know that the 80% and 40% are likely to overlap, but do not know the extent. Some people do the method I've written above, others do things like 1-[(1-.8)*(1-.4)]. In my mind, the method written in my original post does not take into account the overlap.

Comment: I need to go back and get some probability texts with exercises so I can really understand these rules and how they apply in different situations.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight This is a good example of why it's usually not a good idea to discuss people in comments--no matter how well-intended the comments are--because when you do, messages are too easy to misinterpret. (I suspect most of the times I have gotten into trouble here arose from breaking that rule.) If you can, please stick to discussing the substance of the question. Jerome, you might appreciate learning about "odds" and "odds ratios": the math for updating them is particularly simple, which is one reason they are frequently used instead of probabilities.

Comment: Perhaps I set you all up for breaking rules with my style of question. Apologies. Off to read the guidance on posting alongside my probability basics!

Comment: Jerome, if the 80% and 40% reductions in risk are from different studies, then it's a bit more complicated. You'd need to carefully evaluate if the study designs and target samples are indeed close enough to be compared. And since you don't know if there are any shared reduction or interaction between the two, you may need to state that you assume both treatments to be independently associated with the outcome, and then suggest a final risk reduction. It may be lower (if the meal reduces some risk that the medicine already has) or higher (if the meal magnifies the effect of the medicine.)